# How to use an IF within a VLOOKUP function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I use an `If` inside a `Vlookup` function in Excel to look for if the *problem status* matches between two sheets knowing that a status column in each sheet differ in terms of letters.

For example the status "Pending" in the first table has to be equal to "Waiting Change Resolution" in the second one.

The next two images represent sheet 1 and 2.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which column you wish to finally update? Is it the Status in the second table? IF Status of Problem-ID in first table = Pending THEN should the Status in second table for the same ProblemID=CRM Number be updated to 'Waiting'? or You wish to run VLOOKUP to retrieve Status from the Second table for each Problem-ID in first where the Status = Pending?

Comment: Ok, that is a good Question because i definitely screwed up while explaining. now it is a matter of a simple Status Check , Each sheet represent a different CRM but Pending in the CRM1 (for ex) is Waiting.. in the CRM2 now in order for things to be alligned it is crucial for me to run a comparison of each Problem's Status in each CRM if Pending (CRM1) = Waiting (CRM2) im good ELSE im screwed.

Thank you so much anyway for your good Question

Comment: You discuss some conditions that must be met, but I'm missing the actual task.  What value are you getting from where that you want to find in which table and return what if you find it, to which you want to apply these conditions?

Comment: Update your question from your comments please. I do not understand what you want to do

Comment: Prasanna thank you sooooo much for your will to help but PAT2015 in his answer below hit the core of my issue , but as i said thank you all.
if you want me to explaain to you more the issue i would like to ( if you are intrested ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding a possible solution could be to wrap VLOOKUP within IF function.

Put the formula in column E in Sheet1

```
=IF(C2="Pending",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$18,2,FALSE)="Waiting Change Resolution","OK","Not-OK"),"")
```

[image]

In case the Problem ID does not exist in Sheet2 it shall return #N/A

Comment: Thank you Pat2015 ill try this just the case of the existance it has been treated and i've dealt but it is my bad i kept present in the exemple, but it wouldnt hurt to mix it here , thank you big time, I'll try this and some ideas i'm having even while sleeping :) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a column beside status and hide it, or put it anywhere on the far right so that it won't appear in the sheet. In that column put this formula

```
=IF(C3="Pending", "Waiting Change Resolution", "")
```

Then in the vlookup function just match the value of that new column to the table in the other sheet

Comment: Thank you for your reply i'll try it , hopefully it'll perfect :)

Comment: For More precision the Function should do :
1 - Pick up PROBLEM number from the sheet1 table
2 - Check its status
3 - Go the Other Sheet
4 - Find The same PROBLEM
5 - Check the status in the Sheet 2
6 - If Pending= waiting... ==> OK
7 - Else ==> NOK